# A function declaration that I do not understand

Tags: c++

When looking through an API today I came across some a function declaration that looks alien to me.

`GLAPI void GLAPIENTRY glColor3b (GLbyte red, GLbyte green, GLbyte blue);`

How should the first 3 tokens be interpreted? I did not know what to google on this one...

Comment: Or [this](https://community.khronos.org/t/glapientry-and-variations/24380)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLAPI` and `GLAPIENTRY` are going to be macros.  They are going to expand to platform specific tokens that describe how the symbol is mangled, what the calling convention is (if not the default), and how the symbol should be found (statically or dynamically).

OpenGL uses macros like this because the same header file works on multiple different compilers and often OSes.  Other parts of the header file use the preprocessor to query which compiler/OS they are on, and change those preprocessor tokens to do the "right" thing on that platform.

As for `void`, it means the function returns nothing.

If you create a function pointer to `glColor3b` you may have to care about what those tokens do, as function pointers often carry calling convention information in them.  In addition, if your build setup is screwed up, you might get errors (linking errors for example) spawning from them.  But other than those cases, you can ignore them.

On 3 different compilers, it might expand to:

```
extern void glColor3b (GLbyte red, GLbyte green, GLbyte blue);

__declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall glColor3b (GLbyte red, GLbyte green, GLbyte blue);

__stdcall void glColor3b (GLbyte red, GLbyte green, GLbyte blue);
```